# Is there a way to list out my datastores if I've deployed to a VNET?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I followed the instructions in the [MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-enable-virtual-network), but now I can't list our my Datastores either via the SDK nor the Azure Machine Learning studio.

Instead, in the studio I see this:
[image]

Is there a way to make this work? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a blob datastore or file store? We only support blob store behind vnet right now. Can you also check whether you grant your own machine permission to access the storage account inside vnet? in the firewall rule for your storage account, make sure your machine ip is granted to access the storage account.

Let me know how it works.

Comment: The issue is that in the new Azure ML studio experience I can’t list out _any_ datastores- blob store, file store, SQL, etc. This is the same in the SDK. If I try to list all datastores in the workspace, I’m running into this same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share how you created your workspace, set up vnet for your workspace storage account?

I did the following and am able to see my datastore list via both SDK and UI

1. created workspace
2. put my workspace storage account behind vnet
3. go to studio, datastores: no problem seeing the list of my datastores, including the ones behind vnet
   [image]
4. in notebook, call `workspace.datastores`: no problem seeing the list of my datastores, including the ones behind vnet
   [image]